# Where is RCS in Xcode 5.0.1 OS X 10.9

Tags: rcs, osx-mavericks

The RCS, like ci, co, rlog, etc. can find in Xcode 5.0(with command line developer tool) in mountain lion, but disappear in mavericks with xcode 5.0.1(with command line developer tool).

Is apple abandoned the simple version control tool?

Comment: Any idea where to get a good version of CVS for Mavericks?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I was copied the commands (like ci, co, etc.) from another mac with old version of Xcode to the Mavericks, and place these files in /usr/local/bin/ , it's just works for RCS. So I think you can have a try to CVS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/):

> The CVS and RCS source control tools have been removed from Xcode 5. 11968433

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

1. Used a time machine backup to restore *ci, co, rcs, rcsclean,*
   *rcsdiff, rcsmerge, and rlog* to my directory ~/bin/rcs
2. Unfortunately, the system needs to find them in /usr/bin. I did not
   want to add new files to that directory. So I reluctantly (via terminal and sudo) typed
3. ln -s ~/bin/rcs/* /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to recompile from source, [Rudix](http://rudix.org/packages/rcs.html) is probably the simplest way to install RCS.

The [latest version](http://code.google.com/p/rudix-mountainlion/downloads/detail?name=rcs-5.9.0-0.pkg) installs in /usr/local/bin and run well in Mavericks. You might want to symlink it in /usr/bin afterward.